# Why the ConversionData of appsflyer is cached?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, appsflyer-cordova-sdk

I am developing an ionic app and we have a need of using deeplinks and I am using appsflyer. I call the below mentioned method by passing the devKey and the appID

```
    // initialize appsflyer
initAppsflyer() {

    var onSuccess = function (result) {
        //handle result
        console.log('Appsflyer onSuccess ' + result);

    };

    var onError = function (err) {
        // handle error
        console.log('Appsflyer onError ' + err);
    }
    var options = {
        devKey: '',
        appId: '',
        isDebug: true,
        onInstallConversionDataListener: true
    };
    window.plugins.appsFlyer.initSdk(options, onSuccess, onError);
}
```

when I click on a deep link it opens the app and data loads fine. But when I click on another link it shows the data of the previously clicked link. Have anyone faced this issue when working with apssflyer onelink? if so how to over some this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are noticing is that the onInstallConversionDataListener is only meant to return install attribution data and this data doesn't change unless a user uninstalls and reinstalls the app.

To get deeplinking data that updates with each new deeplink URL, please refer to our onAppOpenAttribution method which is meant to return the deeplink details of the link that most recently triggered the app open:
https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/208874366-Deep-Linking-Step-by-Step#the-onappopenattribution-method-

If you have further questions please reach out to support@appsflyer.com and we'd be happy to assist you.

Best,
Joe Williams
AppsFlyer U.S. Support Engineer

Comment: Thanks Joe for the answer. It was really helpful for me to understand the process. But in the documentation it has only implementation on native apps. Could you please provide me with a documentation or an example on how to implement onAppOpenAttribution on a Cordova (Ionic) app.

Answer (score 1):

New version (4.4.9) is released that supports additional callback for `onAppOpenAttribution`: https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/cordova-plugin-appsflyer-sdk#registerOnAppOpenAttribution

Also you can find [this example](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/cordova-plugin-appsflyer-sdk/blob/master/examples/Ionic3/src/app/app.component.ts#L54) (Ionic3) helpful

```
platform.ready().then(() => {

  // init AppsFlyer
  const options = new AppsFlyerInitOptions();
  options.devKey = AppsFlyerConstants.DEV_KEY;
  options.isDebug = true; // Optional
  options.onInstallConversionDataListener = true;

  if (platform.is('ios')){
    options.appId = AppsFlyerConstants.APP_ID;
  }

  try {
    const onSuccess: Function = (res: any) => {
      // do something with  JSON.parse(res)
    };
    const onError: Function = (err: any) => {
      //..
    };

    const onAppOpenAttributionSuccess: Function = (res: any) => {
      // do something with  JSON.parse(res)
    };
    const onAppOpenAttributionError: Function = (err: any) => {
      //..
    };

    window.plugins.appsFlyer.registerOnAppOpenAttribution(onAppOpenAttributionSuccess, onAppOpenAttributionError);

    window.plugins.appsFlyer.initSdk(options, onSuccess, onError);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error("ERROR: AppsFlyer not initiated", e);
  }

 //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Maxim Shoustin for the answer.

Comment: @Mazim Shoustin this method works fine on android but on iOS when i click on a link which has query parameters, onAppOpenAttributionSuccess triggers and im getting a link in the data object in the response. Though i click on different deeplinks with query params, im getting the same link in the response. any idea what i am missing here?

Comment: @DilanFdo you get old deeplink becuase of issue on server side. The issue will be  fixed shortly

Comment: @Mazim Shoustin thank you for your quick response. please update here once it is fixed. Thanks.